# How do I update a multiple choice question on Google form based on the date selected from a previous question using Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to know if it is possible when a user selects a specific date, update the answer of another question automatically, showing the specific times of that day, using forms script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the date selector widget/question, then this is not possible. The date selector widget/question does not let you jump to a specific section based on the selected date.

If you pre-fill available dates using the multiple choice question, then you can create one section for each date with the times and have the form go to a specific section based on the date selected. Keep in mind, this means you'll have to always update the form when you have new dates/times.